# Restore partition. HELP PLEASE

Tags: windows, hard-drive, mbr, gpt, partition-recovery

I was having some problems with my bios because I got different hard drives, each in different partition tables, some in GPT and others in MBR. So I decided to convert all to GPT using MiniTool Partition Wizard (https://www.partitionwizard.com/).

The thing is when I pressed to start to convert to GPT I remembered that the program I was using (MiniTool Partition Wizard) was actually installed in that Hard Drive and instantly the program closed.
What happened was that the program successfully converted the hard drive to GPT but when it was reallocating the files I guess, the program crashed since the hard drive was ejected. So I got my hard drive now in GPT but all as unallocated space.

Is there any way I can restore the partition without data loss?
I got a lot of important files and really can't lose this.
Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: It is not possible to have both MBR and GPT on the same disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

If your trying to get back the old partition (which may have been lost, the Free Mini Partition Wizard" will not do this try

https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

> "Convert MBR Disk <=> GPT Disk"
>
> ?Question **All partitions got lost after I applied the conversion.**
>   
> Answer: **Could you please send the log file of MiniTool Partition Wizard to support@minitool.com, which is located at the installation directory of the program and called log.txt.**
>
> ? Windows won't boot after you converted the system disk to GPT.
>   
> Firstly, could you please check whether UEFI boot is enabled. 
>   If it is already enabled, could you please take a photo with 
>   your phone to show us the exact boot error?
>
> ? Get the error message "MiniTool Partition Wizard cannot convert this GPT disk to MBR. (Too many primary partitions)
>
> ? MiniTool Partition Wizard cannot convert this GPT disk to MBR. (partition layout exceed 2TB limit)

Please goto https://www.partitionwizard.com/faq.html

Comment: Please note that it is a secondary hard drive, it's not the hard drive that Windows is in. So windows is booting normally.

Comment: Also, the partition does not exceed 2 TB...

Comment: I cannot send any log because as I described in the question, the partition in which the program was also installed was lost, so I don't have any access to the program or any data that was in the hard drive.

Comment: @Mateus Gutemberg Note that if you do try Testdisk unplug any external hard disks (USBs, et cet.) that you don't want to fix. It will be easier to determine which drives you want to work on. Good Luck with that.

Comment: Thank you! Testdisk actually worked.

Comment: I am glad to hear it. Thanks for letting us all know it helped I like that tool ; -)